# Problem to listen a event after logout (the event was fired when I was logged in) - EventEmitter2

Tags: node.js, node-modules, eventemitter

I have 4 files:

The **AuthenticationUtil.js** fires a event when I log in and log out. Then, it invokes each authStatusListeners' function:

```
const authUtilEmitter = new EventEmitter.EventEmitter2({
    wildcard: true,
    delimiter: '::',
    maxListeners: 0
});

// METHODS
function emitLoginEvent(userData, oAuthConfig) {
    userData.user_name = userData[oAuthConfig.usernameProperty];
    const authData = {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        userData: userData
    };
    _emitLoginStateChangeEvent(authData);
}

function emitLogoutEvent(evtData) {
    const authData = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userData: null,
        evtData
    };
    loginResult = q.defer();
    loginResult.reject();
    _emitLoginStateChangeEvent(authData);
}

function _emitLoginStateChangeEvent(authData) {
    authUtilEmitter.emit('loginState::change', authData);
    authStatusListeners.forEach(listener => listener(authData));
}
```

I have a Service **AuthenticationService.js** to register the listeners:

```
function addLoginStateChangeListener(listener) {
    authStatusListeners.push(listener);
}
```

And I have the file **OAuthUtil.js** that is where I need to listen the event:

```
function getAuthorizeUrl() {
  AuthenticationService(oAuthConfig).addLoginStateChangeListener((authData) => {
        console.log('Good work!');
  });
}
```

When I'm logging in I was able to print out the message in the console. The problem is when I am logging out, the 'loginState::change' was fired, the logout was executed and I entered in the getAuthorizeUrl but I can't listen the event.